# Pass PHP value to external JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, php

I have in example1.com/dir/index.php?id=name

```
<?php  
$id=$_GET['id'];
?>
<script type="text/javascript">var id= <?= $id?>;</script>
<script src="custom.js"></script>
```

How can i fix this for get the var id in custom.js
I have this in original but i need change it::

```
if(screenWidth < 991){
            var page_url    =   'https://' + window.location. pathname+ window.location.pathname;
            if(page_url.indexOf('xhtml') == -1){
                window.location.href = page_url.replace('dir/index.html', 'dir/xhtml/onboading.html');
            }
        }
```

I need change the page_url for go to other domain but dont work:

```
if(screenWidth < 991){
            var page_url    =   'https://' + id '.example2.com';
            if(page_url.indexOf('xhtml') == -1){
                window.location.href = page_url.replace('dir/' + id '', 'https://' + id '.example2.com');
            }
        }
```

Any help would be gratefully appreciated
Thanks!

Comment: You're passing the variable correctly. The problem is that you're missing `+` between `id` and `'.example2.com'`. I suggest you use a template literal instead of concatenation, it's easier to read and write.

Comment: I assume `$id` is a number. If it's a string, it needs to be put in quotes in the `var id` declaration. Then use `var id = <?= json_encode($id) ?>`

Comment: @Barmar $id is a name for redirect to subdomain in var page_url.

Comment: use `json_encode()` to format it correctly for JS, regardless of the type.

Comment: @Barmar I use in the index.php <script type="text/javascript">var id = <?= json_encode($id) ?></script> and I get the variable correctly but in the custom.js?

Comment: Did you fix the typo in `custom.js`? `id '.example2.com'` should be `id + '.example2.com'`

Comment: Yes and i get error of sintaxis:
var page_url = 'https://' + id + '.qrhotelinfo.com';
   if(page_url.indexOf('php') == -1){
    window.location.href = page_url.replace('demo/index.php', 'https://' + id + '.qrhotelinfo.com');

Comment: I don't see the syntax error. The browser should show you exactly where the error is when you click on the line number.

Comment: Working now!! thansk very much @Barmar

Answer (score 0):

get that id by js file

```js
var id = document.getElementById('id').value;
```

Comment: <input type="hidden" id="id" value="<php echo $id;?>"> in php file